# Simplest method of avoiding memory leaks in 2-window scenario

Tags: wpf, events, memory-leaks

I have two windows: a **master** window, and a **details** window which is opened by double-clicking on a specific row in the datagrid of the master window. I would like to refresh the master window's datagrid control when the data in the details window is saved.

(Some irrelevant details: each window inherits from a `BaseWindow` class, and has its own copy of a class inheriting from EF5 `DbContext`. I've added a `Save` event to the partial class and overridden `SaveChanges` to raise this event whenever `SaveChanges` is called. That is actually the event to which I am attaching an event handler.)

I know I can do this by attaching an event handler to the `Save` event. However, I have no idea in which order the windows will be closed - if the master window is closed first, there will still be a reference to it held by the instance of the details window.

If I listen to the `Closing'/'Closed` event of the master window so I can tell when to release the handler attached to the 'Save' event, I will have the same problem in reverse -- the master window will hold a reference to the details window even after the details window is closed.

I am aware that I can implement a `WeakEventManager` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx), but I would like to know if there is a simpler technique I can use. (I've been told I have a tendency to overcomplicate things.)

(I am not using MVVM.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WeakEventManager` would do the job, just use the generic version and there's nothing complicated about it. Performance wise that should be perfectly fine in your case.

A different option would be to unsubscribe the event handler on `Closing` of the master window from the master window as you said.

To remove all references when the details window is closed, unsubsribe all event handlers from within the detail window when the detail window closes, by subscribing this method to the `Closing` event:

```
public OnClosing()
{       
    Delegate[] registeredDelegates = saveHandler.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (Delegate d in registeredDelegates )
       saveHandler-= (d as SaveDelegate);
}
```

where saveHandler is your handler and SaveDelegate is your custom delegate type.

That being said, if you want to get rid of your overcomplication image, just don't care...